# Android app force closes after splash screen if I use specific background image

Tags: android, android-manifest, splash-screen

This is confusing me quite a bit.  If I set the android:background to a PNG I designed specifically for the splashActivity, the app closes after the three seconds the image is displayed.

If I use the same android:background image that's used on the mainActivity, the app runs just fine.  It also runs fine if I don't include a background in the xml.

The only difference is I'm using a different background image.  The splash image I'm using is definitely located in drawable-hdpi, and it's definitely referenced in R.java.

Any ideas?

Logocat, this is only shown when I use the splash image I want to use:

```
08-01 16:09:39.557: D/AndroidRuntime(15794): Shutting down VM
08-01 16:09:39.557: W/dalvikvm(15794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a471f8)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moboing.abcblast/com.moboing.abcblast.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #826: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #826: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at com.moboing.abcblast.Main.onCreate(Main.java:28)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    ... 11 more
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    ... 24 more
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
08-01 16:09:39.572: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    ... 27 more
```

Comment: You're running out of memory using the bitmap. How large is this image?

Comment: You're getting an OutOfMemoryError. What are the dimensions of this splash image?

Comment: The 24bit PNG version of the image is 329K.  I also tried a JPG version which was 165.6k.  What's really strange is the one that doesn't error that I use in the other activity, it's 754kb.  The dimension of both the images are the same, 480x854

Comment: I experimented by adding one that's only 2kb, and it still errors.

Comment: That does seem odd. What is line 826 of the XML file you're using in `setContentView` on line 28 of Main.java?

Comment: Line 826 is "final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);"

Comment: One thing that is strange, in the graphical layout when I select the relativelayout for the activity, in the properties, for Background it has the value, "drawable/splash (H:\htdocs\android\.." etc..  It's showing the physical directory from which I copied and pasted the graphic file.  The other images I have and other background of the mainactivity does not have the (H:\htdocs..) at the end of the drawable?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing an actual filesystem path when referencing a resource in xml. What happens if you just remove that so it says `android:background="@drawable/splash"`? If that doesn't work, try removing all versions of the image and adding it to your resources again. Make sure it's actually copied into your drawable directories. Also, sometimes doing a Project > Clean in Eclipse gets rid of odd things. Can your background image be tiled? Screen sizes vary, so a 480x854 image will only fit perfectly on specific devices.

Comment: Karakui, thanks.  I did all of what you said above and it worked.  The part that finally worked was adding the image into all of the drawable directories (I've only been putting my images in the drawable-hdpi folder).  Is it advisable to create an instance of every image (there's a lot, like 52 images) in each folder??  Either way, it works.  Thanks.